# How do I connect esp32 bluetooth with Windows 10 using a 5.0 bluetooth adapter?

Tags: windows, arduino, bluetooth, esp32

I'm trying to send data from an esp32 (Arduino) to my PC program written in Java. I have a bluetooth 5.0 adapter (HOMMIE 5.0) and I can't pair those two. When I try to pair them the esp32 prints on the arduino serial monitor this error message: `ASSERT_WARN(103 23), in lc_task.c at line 8775ASSERT_WARN(103 24), in lc_task.c at line 877`.
Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Missing some essential information. Are you using basic bluetooth, or bluetooth low energy (BLE)? It makes a difference. How is your ESP32 bluetooth setup?

Comment: I discovered that it's not a Java problem. The problem is with my esp32: when I try to connect it to my Bluetooth 5.0 adapter it prints an error message on the Arduino serial monitor: ASSERT_WARN(103 23), in lc_task.c at line 8775. I don't know what it means and how to solve it

Comment: The problem is I don't know what file is lc_task.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here, but actually there's a way that i found how to make it work (not my favorite i got to say). But basically, if you downgrade the version of the add-on esp32 in the arduino IDE from 1.0.6 to 1.0.4 it should work, or at least it workerd for me. At the end i don't really know the cause of the issue, but at least its a partial solution

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've posted the same question on GitHub and I forgot to update this thread. However, I used your exact same solution and it works just fine for me. After a long research, I still don't know what causes the problem. Cheers!